# Does indexedDB support importing dictionary-like files produced from other storage mechanisms?

Tags: indexeddb

As I understand it, `Indexeddb` is a way to store and retrieve data from a database on the client side.

I see a lot of examples how to build and fill such a database, but I never find an example where the whole database is already built and just loaded in.

I have a large dictionary of 100.000 words that I would like to store in a database. But reading the words and building such a database on the client side would take too long on a slow mobile device. So i thought, build the `indexeddb` on the server and just load it somehow. Or load it from a local url when the webpage is wrapped in Phonegap (website as a mobile app).

Is there any way this can be done, or am I on the wrong track here?

Answer (score 0):

No, Its not possible to build the IndexedDB database on server and then put it in browser.

**You need to create a database and then dump your data into that on the browser itself**.

In a way, you are asking for restore/backup functionality of a browser databases. As of now, it is not possible. 
IndexedDB being asynchronous in nature, you can definitely dump data without stopping your user from using the application.

Answer (score 0):

@Dylan you said Quote > "build the indexeddb on the server"

It will be same as you having your current database on server side.
The motive of indexeddb is using database on client side.So you will have to get the data on client and create and store it in the indexeddb.

Possibly you are on wrong track.But I guess its better if you do some ajax calls and store it on client side on document ready or something and user can use it on the pages later on.